# Python3: Interpolation for certain points (not grid)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, linear-interpolation

I have a text file (data.txt) with this format(x y z):

Example:

```
1.1 0.0 12
1.2 2.2 15
1.3 5.5 30
2.6 1.0 20
2.1 4.8 31
3.9 0.5 12
...
```

I get this data with the following code:

```
x,y,z = np.genfromtxt(r'data.txt', unpack=True)
```

I want to do an interpolation to find the z value of certain set of points. Example:

(1.0; 1.0),   (1.9; 3.05),   (1.4; 4.0),   (2.2; 0.9),  (2.4; 2.1),  (2.9; 3.0),    (3.0; 1.8)

What I do is to create a text file ("points.txt") with these points and load them with

```
positions_path = np.loadtxt("points.txt")     #(x, y)
```

This is my code to compute the interpolation:

```
intial_points = np.transpose(np.vstack((x, y)))   #array with the x and y points from data.txt



L1 = []  #empty list 

for i in range(len(positions_path)):


    n1=float(interpolate.griddata(intial_points, z, (positions_path[i,0], positions_path[i,1] ), method='linear'))   


    #L1 saves  x, y, z  
    L1.append([positions_path[i,0], positions_path[i,1], n1])
```

This does the job. The problem is that it is not feasible for a larger number of points. 
I am basically doing an interpolation for each point. If I have 10000 points, I will have to do it 10000 times.

I know I can do create a certain grid and get the values for a discrete grid. But what if I get the value for a point like (0.001, 0.25)?  I would have to have very fine grid. This is the reason why I am avoiding grids.

Is there a way to do the interpolation for 1000 points at once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple:

```
n1=interpolate.griddata(intial_points, z, (positions_path[:,0], positions_path[:,0] ), method='linear')
```

It returns an array with the "z" values of the points in points.txt. No need for a grid. 
Thanks!